# GAX/GAT alternatives for Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, t4, guidance-automation-tool

I would like to give guidance for my team. With VS.NET 2k5 and 2k8 we had *Guidance Automation* but now it's gone.

I know the free alternative (Open GAT/GAX) but I dont really like it.

As far I know T4 templates are not good choice for that.

**What we need**:

- fix type: class library
- setting build output
- creating namespaces, folders
- creating files

Answer (score 1):

See [GAX 2010 For Visual Studio 2013](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/0ba6e8d1-b4e6-43b4-93f6-49a99a6c4372) and [GAT 2010 for Visual Studio 2013](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/4e9b9525-2c99-47f7-877b-1b25ca10c377), both by [Jelle Druyts](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/site/search?f%5B0%5D.Type=SearchText&f%5B0%5D.Value=gax&f%5B1%5D.Type=User&f%5B1%5D.Value=Jelle%20Druyts&f%5B1%5D.Text=Jelle%20Druyts).

I haven't used either one (I used GAT/GAX back some years ago, along with the Web Service Software Factory), but I look forward to hearing from you how well they work.

Comment: It was too much for me, finally we decided to use VS.NET Project Templates. To be honest they are far from perfect but fits the minimum requirements.